# Map member field in SWIG

Tags: c++, swig

Suppose, I've written the following mapping:

```
/* File : gmpy.i */
%module gmpy

%{ #include "gmpy.h" %};

%include <stl.i>

namespace std {
    %template(_string_list) vector< string >;
}

%newobject makeRunCalibrationParam;
%delobject delRunCalibrationParam;

%typemap(in) _string_list {
  /* Check if is a list */
  if (PyList_Check($input)) {
    int size = PyList_Size($input);
    $1.resize(size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      PyObject *o = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
      if (PyString_Check(o))
        $1[i] = PyString_AsString(PyList_GetItem($input,i));
      else {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"list must contain strings");
        return NULL;
      }
    }
  } else {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"not a list");
    return NULL;
  }
}

%include "gmpy.h"
```

It does work when i map python list of strings to function argument such as `void foo(const std::vector<std::string>& arr)`. However, I've got no idea how to map it to a struct field:

```
struct Foo {
   std::vector<std::string> field;
};
```

It says

```
TypeError: in method 'Foo_field_set', argument 2 of type 'std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > > *'
```

AFAIU it's supposed to recognize argument type for the setter method and match the approriate type converter. Why it doesn't and how to extend this converted without excess code duplication?